# 404 error on file that IS ON SITE

Tags: php, mysql, http-status-code-404

Okay, so on my site for some odd reason, I get a 404 error that is on a file that all says its on the site. Create.php does not show up. Just 404's (Along with aaa.php, but I can still use HTTP services to access it.) 
This is the image of my file list: http://ctrlv.in/485842

This is my 404 error: http://ctrlv.in/485844

Last but not least, this is my code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "robx10ho_users";
$password = "fakiefakie";
$dbname = "robx10ho_usersuse";
$usn = $_REQUEST['usn'];
$psw = $_REQUEST['psw'];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO login (Username, Password)
VALUES ($usn, $psw");

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: From your file list, can you click on `Create.php`?

Comment: Yes, but it just 404's after that.

Comment: I tried it, i got the 404 on the first click, and it worked the second time i tried.

Comment: I can access here: http://rob.x10host.com/Create.php

Comment: That does not work for me sadly.

Comment: I would recommend you getting a reliable and paid host, its like as cheap as maybe 12 euro's a year or so, including a domain name.

Comment: I think there's something funky going on on the server, rather than in your PHP code.

Comment: @KoenHoeijmakers the thing is, I have a spare comp. But it needs ram. I am stuck with this free crap.

Comment: Ok, got it to work with http requests's. Error in code. But it still 404's just like aaa.php

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your files exist on the server? Did you check that they are there via ftp for instance?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine, your problem is probably your host, you could try adding another page for testing purposes, so you can see if it just that page or every.

Also very **IMPORTANT** dont post your database security details, just leave it out. We can allways look at your code without having those important details.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably on the server and not in `PHP`.
I am taking a guess that files are not there but your sitemap is being cached.
Check out if your files exist on the server using `FTP` or `SSH` connection (if possible).